# Salesforce Aura Component Tip

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, javascript-controller, hack

Is there a way to see **Aura component** and its js controller in production org?
I don't have access to developer console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not.

Lightning components must be viewed through the developer console.
The only option without access to the developer console is going to Setup -> Lightning components, and viewing the high-level details like Name, Created Date, ... However, it redirects to the developer console for further details like the components code.